# can't add a new column with a function applied to another column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm applying a function called "divs" to column "Dividends", and want a new column "B" with the outputs of the function: if the value in Dividends is >0, it will print "Right" and if not it will print "Wrong"

The function works and returns a "series" with the right outputs from the function. HOWEVER, the dataframe with the new column B is equal to the original column Dividends without the function.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong because I am creating a new column and the function is applying, but not together.

```
df["B"] = df.Dividends.apply(divs)



def divs(paid):
    if paid >0:
        print("Right")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
    return paid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing rather than returning. Replace `print("Right")` with `return "Right"` and same thing for `print("Wrong")` and you should be ok.